# How to maintain table layout fluid column widths?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using JQuery UI Sortable for a table. The problem is that the table column widths are not maintained when there is only 1 row and that row is being dragged using sortable, essentially leaving no physical row in the table. I did some googling and found out that I can use `table-layout: fixed` for my table to maintain the width. But that makes the table columns all of fixed size. I want the columns to be dynamically sized but still maintain the widths when no row exists in the table.

[image: When row is dragged, column widths reset]

Comment: can you share your code, if possible [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: This is not really easy to do. It would mean saving the widths of the columns if there is only one row and giving the columns those widths when the row is dragged away. Then you'd have to remove all that again when there's a row again. There's no quick fix for this, it's just how tables behave based on content.